# how to reload xml document

Tags: xml, winforms, reload

I have a xml file which I modify with the following code:

```cs
 XmlDocument xlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Program Files (x86)", "Product.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string sfile = files[0];
            xlDoc.Load(sfile);
            XmlNodeList list = xlDoc.SelectNodes("//dependancy");
  XmlNode foundNode = xlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//dependancies//dependancy[@name='Microsoft Windows NT']");
int found = list.Count;

  if (foundNode == null)
  {
      foundNode = xmlElement;
      list[found - 1].AppendChild(foundNode);
      xlDoc.Save(sfile);
      ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sfile);
  }

  foreach (XmlNode node in list)
  {
      xlDoc.Load(sfile);
      try
      {//use inserted node}
      ...
```

Now before the foreach is executed , I want to reload the XML document, so that the value is in the document. The problem I am experiencing is that the changes are only loaded if the application is restarted. How can I reload the file before moving on to the foreach segment?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: xlDoc already contains the data you wish (it was used to create the exact file you wish to reload).  There is no need to reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's some pretty confusing code; I assume `xmlElement` is a `<dependancy name='Microsoft Windows NT'/>` element you have created elsewhere.

`//` in XPath expressions search all elements, so `//dependancies//dependancy[@name='Microsoft Windows NT']` is the same as `//dependancy[@name='Microsoft Windows NT']`. Assuming there is already at least one `<dependancy .../>` element, then

```
list[found - 1].AppendChild(foundNode);
```

Will insert your `xmlElement` as a child inside the last existing `<dependancy .../>` element; like this:

```
<dependancies>
    <dependancy>
        <dependancy name="Microsoft Windows NT" />
    </dependancy>
</dependancies>
```

That must be what you have, otherwise `list[found - 1]` will crash.

> The problem I am experiencing is that the changes are only loaded if the application is restarted.

That is not correct. You already have the change in `list[found - 1]`. The real problem is that is not what you are searching:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in list)
```

That searches all children of `list`, not children of `list[found - 1]`. I am guessing that what you want is:

```
<dependancies>
  <dependancy />
  <dependancy name="Microsoft Windows NT" />
</dependancies>
```

To get that, replace `XmlNodeList list = xlDoc.SelectNodes("//dependancy");` with:

```
XmlNode dependancies = xlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//dependancies");
```

Replace `list[found - 1].AppendChild(foundNode)` with:

```
dependancies.AppendChild(foundNode)
```

And `foreach (XmlNode node in list)` with:

```
foreach (XmlNode in dependancies.ChildNodes)
```

If that is not what you want, please clarify.

The reason you are getting your new `xmlElement` when you run the program again is because `xlDoc.SelectNodes("//dependancy")` searches all nodes, including those in `<dependancy .../>`.

Also, what does "dependancy" mean? Do you mean "dependency"? Misspellings are very, very confusing.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve! Thanx you very much for a very detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Is sfile an object of type Stream? If so, you may need to flush your stream and then resetting the position of that stream to 0.

```cs
  if (foundNode == null)
  {
      foundNode = xmlElement;
      list[found - 1].AppendChild(foundNode);
      xlDoc.Save(sfile);
      ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sfile);
  }

  // Reset position of stream
  sfile.Flush();
  sfile.Position = 0;

  foreach (XmlNode node in list)
  {
      xlDoc.Load(sfile);
      try
      {//use inserted node}
      ...
```

If not, please provide a more detailed example with types well defined for each variable.

Comment: sfile is the actual xml doc. Edited my original post to include this.